# Hide a form when it is submitted and form2 appears

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two forms in a page, form1 one appears when the page is loaded and when the form is submitted, form2 appears. Problem is I want form1 to be hidden when form2 appears so i have on form visible at a time. I believe I can achieve this with jquery but don't know how. My code sample is shown below

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> " method="post" id="button">
      <label for="student_id" class="select"> Month of the Year </label>
      <select name="months" id="months">
      <option value="01">Jan</option>
      <option value="02">Feb</option>
      <option value="03">Mar</option>
      </select> 
      <input type="submit" id="form1" name="button" value=" Display Day">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['form1'])){

echo"<form name=\"form2\" action=\"form.php\" method=\"post\" >
      <label for=\"day\" class=\"select\">Day of the Month</label>
      <select name=\"month\" id=\" month \">
      <option value=\"01\"> Monday </option>
      <option value=\"02\"> Tuesday </option>
      <option value=\"03\">Wednesday</option>
      </select> 
      <input type=\"submit\" name=\"link\" value=\" Display Month\">
</form>";
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#form1').on('submit',function(){
      // make your form1 check here
      // hide form1
      $('#form2').slideDown(500);
      $(this).slideUp(500);
      return false;
     });
});
```

dont forget to include jquery library

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via JQuery, but that's not necessary since you are only writing the 2nd form if the 1st form was submitted.  Make this an if/else in PHP and your problem is solved...

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['form1'])){

echo"<form name=\"form2\" action=\"form.php\" method=\"post\" >
      <label for=\"day\" class=\"select\">Day of the Month</label>
      <select name=\"month\" id=\" month \">
      <option value=\"01\"> Monday </option>
      <option value=\"02\"> Tuesday </option>
      <option value=\"03\">Wednesday</option>
      </select> 
      <input type=\"submit\" name=\"link\" value=\" Display Month\">
</form>";
} else {
echo"<form name=\"form1\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\" id=\"button\">
      <label for=\"student_id\" class=\"select\"> Month of the Year </label>
      <select name=\"months\" id=\"months\">
      <option value=\"01\">Jan</option>
      <option value=\"02\">Feb</option>
      <option value=\"03\">Mar</option>
      </select> 
      <input type=\"submit\" id=\"form1\" name=\"button\" value=\" Display Day\">
</form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks all for the contribution. Since I can achieve it without jquery that suits me fine. Thank's all

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without jquery.

first you can start if in php and then write html then write the closing brace under it.
second you should place your first form under another if.

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['form1'])){ ?>
<form name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> " method="post" id="button">
      <label for="student_id" class="select"> Month of the Year </label>
      <select name="months" id="months">
      <option value="01">Jan</option>
      <option value="02">Feb</option>
      <option value="03">Mar</option>
      </select> 
      <input type="submit" id="form1" name="button" value=" Display Day">
</form>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['form1'])){ ?>

      <form name="form2" action="form.php" method="post" >
      <label for="day" class="select">Day of the Month</label>
      <select name="month" id=" month ">
      <option value="01"> Monday </option>
      <option value="02"> Tuesday </option>
      <option value="03">Wednesday</option>
      </select> 
      <input type="submit" name="link" value=" Display Month">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jQuery to bind a handler to the first form's [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$("FIRST FORM SELECTOR").submit(function(event) {
    $("SECOND FORM SELECTOR").show();
    $( this ).hide();
}
```

To initially hide the second form use something like:

```
<form style="visibility: hidden;">...</form>
```